# Meaning of the phrasal verb "to dart at"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

> There was the poor bear, spluttering away in the water, and trying his hardest to swim whilst the goldfish darted at him in fury.

What does *to dart at* mean in this context? Does it mean "attack"?

Comment: I think this should be general reference: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dart?s=t

Comment: I know what "dart" normally means. I have a dictionary. but "dart at" in this context? I have no clue, and dictionaries were of no help to me.

Comment: It's really simple, actually. You scroll down to the intransitive verb in the Dictionary.com entry, and you find that *dart* means, "to move swiftly; spring or start suddenly and run swiftly". Then you infer that *to dart at* means, "to move swiftly **at**; spring or start suddenly and run swiftly **at**", and there you have it.

Comment: OK I do need this translated into Arabic. Well in Arabic it wouldn't sound natural if I say the goldfish is moving rapidly at the bear. So I do need the **connotation** not the denotation. goldfish making it hard for him to swim? attacking him?? helping him?

Comment: It isn't a phrasal verb.  It hasn't been lexicalized (reinterpreted as a single element) or idiomatized (given idiomatic meaning you cannot figure out from the individual elements).  I think the connotation, if any, comes from *darted*.  The goldfish was moving (figuratively) *like a dart*.

Comment: "So I do need the connotation not the ***denotation***" - who said anything about denotating the goldfish? - It's not a bomb! And "the goldfish is NOT moving rapidly ***at*** the bear" - it's moving ***towards*** the bear. We cannot help you translate English into Arabic, since **we** don't know what 'sounds natural' in Arabic.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, dart is Verb, it means "To move suddenly and rapidly", check here http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dart.

Those goldfish are moving rapidly at him. I think it's understandable